# Cylinder defined on 3d coordinate plane

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

This is the first time, I have seen a problem like this:

[image]

I feel as though if i knew where to start i would be able to do this problem easily. In other words, question 1-4 make sence to me and i know what they are asking for, but i just can't visualize the cylinder. I'm not asking for a picture(although that would be nice), but clarification on what the question is telling me would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I think you'd better plot a figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have acesss to a plotting software or a scanner right now so I can't provide a precise plot, but you have the following ingriedents:

1. The equation $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ is the equation of an infinite cylinder of radius $r$ whose symmetry axis is the $z$-axis. The inequality $0 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq r^2$ throws in all the points inside the cylinder and so defines a solid cylinder.
2. The equation $z = y$ is the equation of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that passes through the origin. The inequality $0 \leq z \leq y$ describes the region that lies below the plane and above the $xy$-plane.

The solid $C$ you are interested in lies below the plane $z = y$, inside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ and above the $xy$ plane. The following image, taken from [math.tutorvista.com](http://math.tutorvista.com/calculus/vector-functions.html) shows a similar situation:

[image]

In the picture, $r = 1$ but the plane is $y + z = 2$ and not $z = y$ like in your scenario.

The first part of your question asks you to describe the cross section of $C$ by a plane $x = t$ which is the plane parallel to the $yz$ plane that passes through $(t,0,0)$. In the cross section, $x$ is constant and so the cross section is described by

$$ C_{t} = \left \{ (t, y, z) \, | \, y^2 \leq r^2 - t^2, \, 0 \leq z \leq y \right \}. $$

If you draw the inequalities defining $C_{t}$ in the $yz$ plane, you'll see that $C_{t}$ looks like a solid triangle. This is not surprising as the intersection of the solid cylinder with the plane $x = t$ is a strip and then choosing the points that lie above the $xy$ plane and below the plane $z = y$ will result in a solid triangle (try to imagine and draw this in 3d). This will allow you to do the first part of the question. For the second part of the question, you need to integrate the areas of the cross sections $C_t$ in the range $-r \leq t \leq r$ in order to get the volume of the solid $C$.

Comment: BTW, in the image above, since the plane is $y + z = 2$ doesn't pass through the origin, the intersection of $C$ (considered again to be the points lying below the plane, inside the cylinder and above the $xy$ plane) with the plane $x = t$ will be a right trapezoid instead of a triangle.

Comment: When I try to plot the points, i can sort of see the triangle, but it has a curvature due to the cylinder, it looks sort of like a wedge. I do not think this is the triangle you are referring to. Am I wrong?

Comment: @RichardWatson It doesn't have any curvature as it lies on the plane $x = t$.

Comment: Thank you, i now see the triangle, making the first 3 pretty simple. For a circular object the derivative of the volume should be the area of the side, making 4 easy as well.