# I don't understand why the graph of a cylinder is $x^2 + y^2 = r$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, 3d, cylindrical-coordinates

When I graph $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in a graphing calculator, I expected to have a circle centred at the origin with a radius of 1.  However, the graphing calculator graphs an infinite cylinder on the z-axis. I don't understand why it's a 3d surface when there is no z in the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Why doesn't it just graph a simple flat circle on the XY axis? Can someone please explain why this graphs a 3d solid when the equation doesn't even depend on z?

Comment: "*when I graph... in a graphing calculator*"  Check your settings.  It sounds like you told it to graph a 3d image.  By telling it to graph a 3d image you told it that $z$ should be considered.  Since $z$ was not present in your expression, then *every* value of $z$ is valid.  If you want just a 2d circle, then graph only on the $x$-$y$ plane.  If you want just a 2d circle while looking in 3d, then include an additional condition in your expression such as $z=0$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870146/cylinder-defined-on-3d-coordinate-plane does this help?

Comment: What does the graph of $x=1$ look like? There's no $y$.

Comment: If $x=1,y=0,z=0$ is it true that $x^2+y^2=1$?  Yes?  Then that is one of (*many*) points on the graph.  If $x=1,y=0,z=1$ is it true that $x^2+y^2=1$?  Yes?  Then that *also* is on the graph.  If $x=1,y=0,z=9873243987$ is it true that $x^2+y^2=1$?  Yes?  You get the picture...

Comment: Thanks everyone,  i now understand why the it goes onto the z-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain, first consider the real $x$-$y$ plane, suppose $r>0$, and use new notation $R^{2}=r$.

When we constrain (key word) $x^{2}+y^{2}=R^{2}$, this plots a circle of radius $R$ in which only points on the circle satisfy the equality. Now consider if we just let $x$ and $y$ "float", or do not use a constraint. The plot of $x^{2}+y^{2}$ is now the entire $x$-$y$ plane and no longer a circle. View a contour plot and you'll see different colors, sure, but now any point on the plane satisfies the form with no constraint; again it's $x^{2}+y^{2}$.

Now consider the $x$-$y$-$z$ space with the constrained form $x^{2}+y^{2}=R^{2}$. Well, now $z$ is just floating. So we can stretch the $x$-$y$ plane's circle in our $x$-$y$-$z$ space since literally any $z$ satisfies $x^{2}+y^{2}=R^{2}$. This comes with the consequence that the cylinder you're observing is hollow - "a straw".

To summarize, it's about plotting every point given the constraint. Because $x^{2}+y^{2}=R^{2}$ doesn't constrain $z$, literally every $z$ satisfies and thus a circle that exists at every $z$-value; cylinder.